# How to adjust arrow position in PHP in Vim

Tags: vim

```
$a => 'a';
$bbbbb => 'b';
$cc => 'cccccc';
```

Is there any solution in Vim to make the structure like

```
$a     => 'a';
$bbbbb => 'b';
$cc    => 'cccccc';
```

Comment: Youre looking for the plugins Tabular or Align. (Off to look for a duplicate)

Comment: I have (old?) Align plugin, armed with it, `:%Align =>` will do the formatting.

Comment: @FDinoff `7 Delete this question and go search Google.` :D :D

Answer (score 0):

See Vim's **tabular** plugin.
[Tabular plugin at GitHub](https://github.com/godlygeek/tabular)
[Vimcast's screencast showing basic usage](http://vimcasts.org/episodes/aligning-text-with-tabular-vim/)

Comment: If my answer was helpful and solved your problem, please mark it as accepted. See `help` link at the top for site usage instructions.